# fastapi showing error out of system resource

Tags: python, python-3.x, fastapi

this is my code to retrieve details from database and code is working as expected but i am getting below error while increasing the load. I am not closing the sql connection in the code is that a problem ? can you suggest how to get rid of the below error

i am getting below error, I am using ubuntu 20.x and MS odbc sql driver 18

```
import uvicorn
import pyodbc
import json
import datetime
import ast
from fastapi import FastAPI, HTTPException
from fastapi.responses import JSONResponse
from fastapi import FastAPI, Response
from pydantic import BaseModel

app = FastAPI()

# Set connection parameters
server = 'fasfasf.privatelink.database.windows.net'
database = 'sfafa-af-wus2-dev-idm'
username = 'fafafs'
password = 'affaaaa$#'
port = '1433'


# Create a connection string
conn_string = f'DRIVER={{ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server}};SERVER={server},{port};DATABASE={database};UID={username};PWD={password};MARS_Connection=yes;Encrypt=yes;Connection Timeout=30'

pooling_options = {
    "enabled": True,
    "min_connections": 5,
    "max_connections": 100,
    "max_idle_time": 300,
}

conn = pyodbc.connect(conn_string, pooling=True, **pooling_options)



class User(BaseModel):
    signinname: str


@app.post("/user_details")
async def read_user_details(user: User):
    # Retrieve idu value
    signinname = user.signinname
    print(f"Signinname: {signinname}")
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute(f"SELECT idu FROM indirect.usr WHERE cn='{signinname}'")
    row = cursor.fetchone()
    if row is not None:
        idu = row[0]
    else:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=404, detail="No matching idu found for the specified cn.")

    # Retrieve data from various tables
    if idu is not None:
            # separate the first SQL query
        query1 = "SELECT * FROM indirect.usr WHERE idu='%s'"
        cursor.execute(query1 % idu)
        rows1 = cursor.fetchall()
        result1 = [dict(zip([column[0] for column in cursor.description], row)) for row in rows1] if rows1 else [dict(zip([column[0] for column in cursor.description], [None]*len(cursor.description)))]
        json_data0 = json.dumps(result1, default=str)
        input_data = json.loads(json_data0)
        output_data = {"SingleValueAttributes": input_data}
        output_json = json.dumps(output_data, indent=1)

        queries = [
            ("SELECT STRING_AGG(DGID, ',') as  from indirect.usr_DGID WHERE idu='%s' GROUP BY idu", {}),
            ("select STRING_AGG(telephoneNumber, ',') as telephoneNumber from [indirect].[usr_telephoneNumber] WHERE idu='%s' GROUP BY idu", {})
        ]
        # Execute SQL queries and retrieve results
        query_results = []
        for sql_query, default_row in queries:
            cursor.execute(sql_query % idu)
            rows = cursor.fetchall()
            result = [dict(zip([column[0] for column in cursor.description], row)) for row in rows] if rows else [dict(zip([column[0] for column in cursor.description], [None]*len(cursor.description)))]
            query_results.append(result)

        # Flatten results into a single list
        flattened_results = [item for lst in query_results for item in lst]

        # Convert results to JSON format
        json_data1 = json.dumps(flattened_results)

        # Load JSON data into a dictionary
        data = json.loads(json_data1)

        # Transform data from a list of dictionaries to a dictionary of lists
        transformed_data = {}
        for item in data:
            for key, value in item.items():
                if key in transformed_data:
                    transformed_data[key].append(value)
                else:
                    transformed_data[key] = [value]

        # Convert transformed data back to JSON format
        json_data2 = json.dumps(transformed_data)
        data = json.loads(json_data2)

        # Split comma-separated values in the dictionary
        for key in data.keys():
            if isinstance(data[key], list):
                for i in range(len(data[key])):
                    if data[key][i] is not None and ',' in data[key][i]:
                        new_list = data[key][i].split(',')
                        data[key][i:i+1] = new_list

        # Convert modified dictionary back to JSON format
        json_data3 = json.dumps(data)

        # Load original JSON data and modified JSON data into dictionaries
        dict1 = json.loads(output_json)
        dict2 = json.loads(json_data3)

        # Merge dictionaries
        dict1.update(dict2)

        # Convert merged dictionary back to JSON format
        merged_json = json.dumps(dict1, indent=4)

        # Print the merged JSON data
        #print(merged_json)

        return Response(content=merged_json)
```

i am getting below error, I am using ubuntu 20.x and MS odbc sql driver 18

```
socket: <asyncio.TransportSocket fd=7, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM, proto=6, laddr=('0.0.0.0', 80)>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 164, in _accept_connection
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 292, in accept
OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files
socket.accept() out of system resource
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to ensure that you are closing the database after using as it shows too many open files.

```
cursor.close()
```

Comment: `for sql_query, default_row in queries:
            cursor.execute(sql_query % idu)
            rows = cursor.fetchall()
            result = [dict(zip([column[0] for column in cursor.description], row)) for row in rows] if rows else [dict(zip([column[0] for column in cursor.description], [None]*len(cursor.description)))]
            query_results.append(result)
        cursor.close() `

Comment: i have updated code like above still i have same issue